# A Server for IPhone app to exchange location

Tags: iphone, ios, webserver, core-location

I'm trying to connect app to server that receive data from iphones using the app and the server would also response back (Location data) kind of like find your friends but done automatically.  I don't know what server should be used for iPhone apps. Also what language would be used to communicate with the server ?

Any help/direction/articules would be appreciated.

Comment: One option you have would be to use HTTP to communicate between the iPhone and the server and to send messages in JSON or XML. Any server technology ASP.Net, Rails, PHP etc. would be able to provide this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any server, and any language, as long as it's listening to requests on the port your app specifies, and you've configured it properly.

For starters, here is a nice PHP / iOS tutorial to get you up and running, although I'm not saying your final implementation must be in PHP: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the resource that was very helpful, appreciated.